# state of checkbuttons created in loop

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Ive got the following class Cb which does create a checkbutton:

```
class Cb:
    def __init__(self, parent, scrit, *arg, **kwargs):
        self.parent = parent
        self.scrit = scrit
        self.label = Checkbutton(parent,highlightthickness = 3,highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor = "black", text= scrit, wraplength = 300)
         
        self.label.grid(sticky ="nesw")
```

Instances of the class will be created in loop in the following method:

```
def ricerca(paese, contenuto):
                s = "https://www.ecoi.net/en/document-search/?country%5B%5D={}&countryOperator=should&useSynonyms=Y&sort_by=origPublicationDate&sort_order=desc&content={}".format(paese,contenuto)
                print(s)
                html = urlopen(s)


                bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
                col = bsObj.find('ul', { 'class' : 'list-unstyled doc-list'}) #COLONNA LISTA RISULTATI RICERCA
                bol = col.find('li', { 'class': 'doc-listelement'}) #ELEMENTI RISULTATI DALLA RICERCA(NELLA LISTA)
                with open('/home/josquin/pp/lavagnetta.txt', 'r+') as l:
                    for bol in col:
                     

                         tit = bol.find('h4')
                         cont = bol.find('p')
                         #files = bol.find('a')
                         try:
                          resultbox.insert(END,(str(tit.get_text())+'\n'))
                          a = str((tit.get_text())+'\n') 
                         except:
                          print(tit.get_text()+'\n')
                         try:
                          resultbox.insert(END,(cont.get_text()+'\n'))
                          b = str(cont.get_text()+'\n')
                         except: 
                          print(cont.get_text()+'\n')
                         for link in bol.find_all('a', href=True):
                             try:
                                 resultbox.insert(END,(link['href']+'\n'))
                                 c = str(link['href']+'\n')
                             except:
                                 print(link['href']+'\n') 
                         try:
                          resultbox.insert(END,('|||'*50+'\n'))
                          d = ('|||'*50+'\n')
                         except: 
                          print('|||'*50 + '\n')
                         scrit = (a+b+c)
                         lab = Cb(scrollable_frame, scrit)                
                         cv_identities.append(lab)
```

the latter method is the command of a tkinter button, which creates a checkbutton for every result of a search query with the result text as the checkbutton's label. Since the checkbutton are created in loop, im really confused on how can i get the state of the checkboxes and the text of it. cv_identities (last line) is a list that ive tried to print to get name and position of the checkbutton but i dont know what to do with it:

```
[<__main__.Cb object at 0x7f8707413100>, <__main__.Cb object at 0x7f8707413130>, <__main__.Cb object at 0x7f8707413160>, <__main__.Cb object at 0x7f87074131c0>, <__main__.Cb object at 0x7f8707413250>, <__main__.Cb object at 0x7f87074132e0>, <__main__.Cb object at 0x7f8707413370>, <__main__.Cb object at 0x7f8707413400>, <__main__.Cb object at 0x7f8707413490>, <__main__.Cb object at 0x7f8707413520>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a for loop on cv_identities:

```
for cb_instance in cv_identities:
    checkbutton_value = cb_instance.label.get()
    checkbutton_text = cb_instance.scrit
```